# Should I use 'if' instead of 'but' in this sentence

Tags: clauses

Consider this sentence:

> He said he would have called her, but he hadn't got her number.

Can I use "hadn't got" here, or I should use if clause like:

> He said he would have called her if he had got her number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The words "if" and "but" may be similar, but they aren't exactly interchangeable. The word you should use depends on what you are trying to say.

> He said he would have called her, but he never got her number.
>   Paraphrase: *He never got her number; therefore, he didn't call her.*
>
> He said he would have called her, if he had gotten her number.
>   Paraphrase: *If he had gotten her number, he would have called her*.

The phrasing with "if" is a bit more hypothetical.

Comment: So with 'but' I should use simple past "he never got" or "he didn't have" and with 'if' I should use past perfect "he had gotten', right?

Comment: @blinker - I don't think it's that straightforward. There are several ways you can form a sentences with these words, depending on what you are trying to say. _If he had never gotten her number, they would have never started dating. He tried to call her, but she didn't have her phone._ Those are valid sentences, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an *if-then* clause. The correct way to say this is with the past perfect in the “if” clause, and the conditional perfect in the “then” clause:

**He said if he had gotten her number, he would have called her.**

("...if he had gotten her number" is the *if* clause and  "he would have called her" is the *then* clause)

https://data.grammarbook.com/blog/verbs/if-i-would-have-vs-if-i-had/

Comment: So I can't use 'but' with this phrase?

Comment: The if-then clause wouldn't work if you used 'but'.  Simply, the proper structure of saying the sentence in question is "if this happened, then this would have happened." You *can* use the sentence you have now but it's not structurally proper.